# Powershell 2.0 extract certain files from zip (include subdirectories)

Tags: powershell, file, zip, extract, subdirectory

Apologies, this question is scattered on the internet but I have yet to find a satisfactory answer that uses only Powershell 2.0 (with .NET v3.5) - **no external libraries or programs**

I'm using the following code to extract `log.txt` from `ZipFile.zip` (no matter `log.txt`'s location)

```
$Destination = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace('C:\ZipExtractDir')
$ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace('C:\ZipFile.zip')

$Destination.CopyHere(($Zipfile.Items() | where-object {$_.Name -like '*log.txt'}), 1044)
```

- Works if `log.txt` is in directory root `\log.txt`
- Fails if `log.txt` is in a subdirectory `\Subfolder\log.txt`
- Fails if referencing the literal (.zip) path
  `{$_.Name -Like '*Subfolder\log.txt'}` (both double & single quotes fail)
- Have tried using `-eq` `-like` `-contains` `''` `""` `$_.FullName`

---

I'm quite certain that I'm filtering incorrectly - can anyone help with this code so that it will parse subdirectories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you have already done, you can set up the `Shell.Application` namespaces like this. Then you can copy the extracted directory to the destination path.

```
$zipFilePath = "Zipfile.zip"
$destinationPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads"

$zipfile = (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace($zipFilePath)
$destination = (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace($destinationPath)
$destination.CopyHere($zipfile.Items())
```

Then to list the `log.txt` files, we can contruct the full extracted path with [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7). This basically just appends the zip file name from [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8) to the destination path. Then just use `Get-ChildItem` to list the files recursively with the `-Recurse` and `-Filter` switches.

```
$extractedPath = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($zipFilePath))
Get-ChildItem -Path $extractedPath -Filter log.txt -Recurse
```

And to test this for **PowerShell 2.0** we can use `-version 2` with `powershell.exe`:

```
powershell.exe -version 2 .\test.ps1
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to inspect files before extracting, you'll need to recurse the directories yourself. Below is a demo of how this can be done.

```
function New-ZipChildRootFolder 
{
    param 
    (
        [string]$DestinationPath,
        [string]$ZipFileName
    )

    $folderPath = Split-Path -Path $ZipFileName -Leaf

    $destination = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($DestinationPath)

    $destination.NewFolder($folderPath)
}

function Get-ZipChildItems 
{
    param 
    (
        [string]$ZipFilePath,
        [string]$DestinationPath
    )

    $zipfile = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($ZipFilePath)
    $zipFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFilePath)

    Write-Output "Create root zip folder : $zipFileName"
    New-ZipChildRootFolder -DestinationPath $DestinationPath -ZipFileName $zipFileName

    foreach ($item in $zipFile.items()) 
    {
        Get-ZipChildItemsRecurse -Items $item -DestinationPath $DestinationPath -ZipFileName $zipFileName
    }
}

function Get-ZipChildItemsRecurse
{
    param 
    (
        [object]$Items,
        [string]$DestinationPath,
        [string]$ZipFileName
    )

    foreach ($file in $Items.getFolder.Items())
    {
        if ($file.IsFolder -eq $true) 
        {
            Write-Output "Creating folder : $($file.Path)"
            New-ZipChildFolder -Folder $file -DestinationPath $DestinationPath -ZipFileName $ZipFileName
            Get-ZipChildItemsRecurse -Items $file -DestinationPath $DestinationPath -ZipFileName $ZipFileName
        }
        else 
        {
            $filename = Split-Path -Path $file.Path -Leaf
            if ($filename -eq "log.txt")
            {
                Write-Output "Copying file : $($file.Path)"
                New-ZipChildFile -File $file -DestinationPath $DestinationPath -ZipFileName $ZipFileName
            }
        }
    }
}   

function New-ZipChildFile
{
    param
    (
        [object]$File,
        [string]$DestinationPath,
        [string]$ZipFileName
    )

    $destination = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

    $items = $File.Path.Split("\")

    $zipRootIndex = [array]::IndexOf($items, $ZipFileName)

    $path = $items[$zipRootIndex..($items.Length - 2)] -join "\"

    $fullPath = Join-path -Path $DestinationPath -ChildPath $path

    $destination.NameSpace($fullPath).CopyHere($File)
}

function New-ZipChildFolder
{
    param 
    (
        [object]$Folder,
        [string]$DestinationPath,
        [string]$ZipFileName
    )

    $destination = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

    $items = $Folder.Path.Split("\")

    $zipRootIndex = [array]::IndexOf($items, $ZipFileName)

    $folders = $items[$zipRootIndex..($items.Length - 1)]

    $currentFolder = $DestinationPath
    foreach ($folder in $folders)
    {
        $destination.NameSpace($currentFolder).NewFolder($folder)
        $currentFolder = Join-Path -Path $currentFolder -ChildPath $folder
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$zipFilePath = "C:\Zipfile.zip"
$destinationPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads"

Get-ZipChildItems -ZipFile $zipFilePath -DestinationPath $destinationPath
```

Comment: This works - thank you!  I thought I would also mention this blog from 2011 that I eventually landed on:

[Get Child Items in a Zip File Recursively using Windows PowerShell](https://damashiuchi.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/get-child-items-in-a-zip-file-recursively-using-windows-powershell/)